# Strange behavior within MS Word: using Command-Shift-L launches Safari sometimes

Tags: keyboard

It seems that Command-Shift-L were tied to safari. It is however also tied to "create bulleted list" in Word - which is an action I happen to (want to) do frequently.

How does one change or disable the built-in shortcuts for apps (in this case safari) ?

**Update**  I found the following under system preferences | keyboard |shortcuts|apps

[image]

But as you can see there is nothing specific to Safari here.

**Another update** I just closed down Word and opened it up. ***The behavior seems to have been fixed***: bullets are now appearing.  It is very strange that the given key combo had been *consistently and repeatably* redirecting to safari before Word was restarted.

**Yet another update**  This behavior recurs - even after restarting Word. The shortcut works a few times, then a bit later - and I do not understand what triggers the change in behavior - the shortcut changes behavior to **launching Safari**   Just have no idea what is happening here.

Comment: I get the same strangeness in Excel.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue was a bit difficult to find: that shortcut is linked to "Search with Google".  But the result is that Safari is launched - with whatever is in the clipboard as the search query to google.

[image]

The resolution is to uncheck the "Search with Google" checkbox in the services | shortcuts | searching area.  **Afterwards the Mac shortcut for bulleted paragraph works properly (and always)**

Comment: If you think you might ever use the service it's also possible to remove the shortcut instead of disabling service.

Comment: Believe it or not, command-shift-L was opening a new "Sales Receipt" in QuickBooks me. Utterly bizarre when I was actually trying to unflag an email in Mail. Again, I found no "App Shortcuts", but turning this checkbox off seems to have made the problem go away... cross fingers it stays away.

Comment: Update on my previous [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180038/strange-behavior-within-ms-word-using-command-shift-l-launches-safari-sometimes/180065#comment482660_180065). It didn't work. QuickBooks still manages to steal this keystroke somehow.

Answer (score 0):

When Word is the frontmost application, all keyboard shortcuts are sent to it. Therefore ⇧⌘L will create a bulleted list before any other action that is set to it.

⇧⌘L is not a standard keyboard shortcut for Safari, therefore you need to look for whatever app has set up this keyboard shortcut to override Word.

Comment: Actually, Cmd/Shift/L is 'show sidebar' - but that shouldn't affect anything outside of Safari, of course. I've also a Service shortcut for Cmd/Shift/L for "Search with Google" though I've no clue where it came from